\element and \lowercase or \MakeLowercase not working together
I'm using the excellent \elements package and I want the name of the elements to be displayed lowercase as I use it inside a sentence. I tried different approaches but none seems to work :
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[modules]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}

\begin{document}%
    The element \lowercase{\elementname{15}}.
    The element \MakeLowercase{\elementname{15}}.
    The element \MakeLowercase\expandafter{\elementname{15}}.
\end{document}

I get the following result :

The element Phosphorus. The element Phosphorus. The element Phosphorus.

And I would like to get :

The element phosphorus.


Untested but placing \ExpandArgs{e}  before \MakeLowercase might help. Your use of expandafter here is wrong. You need to expand elements before make lowercase kicks in. Here you're trying to run make lowercase on expandafter.

\elementname is a protected macro. so it won't expand. @daleif | but that would be the thing to do if it did.

@cfr hence the untested (was in a bus)

@daleif wasn't a criticism. I wasn't on a bus.

internally, it is using \lowercase to construct the name. so you could extract that directly, probably. or maybe set the thing which sets it in the misnamed title-case temporarily to \relax or something.

@cfr note there are two constructions, it is only using lowercase if not a number? I might have a solution, 2min

Because \elementname is defined as \protected macro which expands to \@elements@element@name and this macro is \protected too, you can use the \expandafter triple in order to expand this double protected macro. The rest of the macro is expandable normally, so \expanded primitive can do necessary work. The argument of the \lowercase primitive must be fully expanded.
The solution can looks like this:
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[modules]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}

\begin{document}%

    The element 
    \lowercase\expandafter{%
         \expanded \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter {\elementname{15}}}.

\end{document}


+1 athough I think you can save one \expandafter by doing \lowercase\expanded{%           \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter {\elementname{15}}}.

The package was written before the author got acquainted with expl3. Likely, the command \elementname is made \protected because it uses \lowercase. But we can easily dispense with it and define \elementname with a *-version that produces the name lowercase.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{elements}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:Nc \__guine_elements_ifisnum:nTF {@elements@ifisnum}
\cs_set_eq:Nc \__guine_elements_getatomname:n {@elements@get@atom@name}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__guine_elements_getatomname:n {e}

\RenewExpandableDocumentCommand{\elementname}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {% *-version: lowercase
    \text_lowercase:n { \__guine_elements_getname:n {#2} }
   }
   {% normal: uppercase
    \__guine_elements_getname:n {#2}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__guine_elements_getname:n
 {
  \__guine_elements_ifisnum:nTF {#1}
   {
    \__guine_elements_getatomname:n {#1}
   }
   {
    \__guine_elements_getatomname:e { \use:c{@elements@atom@number@\str_lowercase:n {#1}} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\elementname{Cu} \elementname{cu} \elementname{11}

\elementname*{Cu} \elementname*{cu} \elementname*{11}

\end{document}


What's the drawback of this method? That it would break if the package code changes. But it's the same with the other methods that have been proposed.

I came up with this similar to wipet's using l3. Is thre a shorter method? \MakeLowercase{\exp_after:wN{%           \exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN{\elementname{15}}}}

This might work, not that it is using internals from elements.sty and trhus might break in the future. Probably a good idea to send a feature request to the maintainer of that package.
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt, answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[modules]{chemmacros}
\chemsetup[phases]{pos=sub}
\usepackage{elements}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\ElementNameLowercase{m}
{
  \tl_set:Ne \l_tmpa_tl { \@elements@get@atom@name{#1} }
  \text_lowercase:n { \l_tmpa_tl }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother


\begin{document}%
    The element \ElementNameLowercase{15}
\end{document}

Looking inside elements.sty we see that
\newrobustcmd*\elementname[1]{\@elements@element@name{#1}}

so we cannot expand it. The macro underneath is also robust
\newrobustcmd*\@elements@element@name[1]{%
  \@elements@ifisnum{#1}
    {\@elements@get@atom@name{#1}}
    {\lowercase{\@elements@get@atom@name{\csuse{@elements@atom@number@#1}}}}%
}

(note how if #1 is s number they run \@elements@get@atom@name, otherwise  they run \lowercase on something). The macro \@elements@get@atom@name is not robust,
\newcommand*\@elements@get@atom@name[1]{%
  \csuse{@elements@atom@name@\romannumeral#1}%
}

so I tried using that.

ah, you looked in the package. :-)

@cfr could probably have used \ShowCommand and get far enough down.

@cfr similar to wipet's method but using l3 \MakeLowercase{\exp_after:wN{%           \exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN\exp_after:wN{\elementname{15}}}}  is there a shorter method?

@yannisl you don't need the first exp_after and if using L3 you may as well use \text_lowercase rather than its \MakeLowercase wrapper

It's working. I'll send a request to the maintainer.

I don't think the problem was how far, but who :(.
